# Python, Set interval in enumerate

Tags: python

Reader is 100. How can execute the function only every 25 loops? In this case the function should be called 4 times.

```
for i, frame in enumerate(reader):
    execute function
```

Comment: ``if i % 25 == 0`` run execute function.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if exist any option in enumerate loop. Some optional argument to do this job.

Comment: Include an if statement which checks if i % 25 == 0.

Comment: do u need the enumerate i as 0,1,2,3 or 0,25,50,75 ?

Comment: @Skycc The answer of Sushanth is perfect and solves the problem I asked. I was just wondering if enumerate has an other option like the one starting from a certain number (enumerate optional argument) but for interval, like the problem I described. That's it and I guess doesn't exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, frame in enumerate(reader):
    if i % 25 == 0: # Check if the remainder by 25 is 0.
        execute function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, len(reader), 25):
   execute function(reader[i], i)
```

Comment: Better to provide a good explanation for good solution